# What is the proper way to create a temporary char* and print to it?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have a helper function that takes an unsigned char array of a fixed length, and returns it as a formatted char *. However, I'm having some problems.

I tried

```
char* byteArrayToString(unsigned char byte[6]) {
    char t[18] = {""};
    char* str = t;
    sprintf(str, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", byte[0], byte[1], byte[2], byte[3], byte[4], byte[5]);
    return str;
}
```

and

```
char* byteArrayToString(unsigned char byte[6]) {
    std::string t = "";
    char* str = t;
    sprintf(str, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", byte[0], byte[1], byte[2], byte[3], byte[4], byte[5]);
    return str;
}
```

and

```
char* byteArrayToString(unsigned char byte[6]) {
    char* str = new char();
    sprintf(str, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", byte[0], byte[1], byte[2], byte[3], byte[4], byte[5]);
    return str;
}
```

The second one results in some side effects of the value of that string being changed.  The first one ends up giving me junk values and the last seg faults (but I can't figure out why).

Comment: _the last seg faults_ -- contemplate exactly how many `char`s you have allocated with `new char()`. :)

Comment: Have you considered having your function return a `std::string`? If so, then is there some reason you chose not to do that?

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm using some libraries that require me to use character pointers in a lot of places, so it's been easier to work with just those to avoid converting back and forth.

Comment: There is a `c_str` method for `std::string` that returns a `const char *` if the `const` isn't a problem you could use that.

Comment: @roviuser: `std::string` manages your memory for you, whereas `char *` does not. You may want to reconsider using `char *`, since `.c_str()` everywhere is probably easier than `free()` everywhere.

Comment: @roviuser: Well if you return a `char *`, then *somebody* has to take responsibility for freeing the memory. If your library doesn't do that, then you have to. If you're doing it anyway, why not return a `std::string` and then pass the `.c_str()` to the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your first one is not in the printing, but in the returning.  You're returning a pointer to an array which has been reclaimed (because it is an automatic variable, its lifetime ends when the function returns).

Instead try:

```
string byteArrayToString(const unsigned char* const byte)
{
    char t[18] = {""};
    sprintf(t, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", byte[0], byte[1], byte[2], byte[3], byte[4], byte[5]);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: @Nawaz: Just showing how close the original code was to working.   And yeah, the C++ standard library includes all the C library functions for a reason, sometimes, they're just more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Proper way is to return `std::string` as:

```
#include <sstream>   //for std::ostringstream
#include <string>    //for std::string
#include <iomanip>   //for std::setw, std::setfill

std::string byteArrayToString(unsigned char byte[6]) 
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
         ss << "0X" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int) byte[i] << ":";
    ss << "0X" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int) byte[5];
    return ss.str();
}
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/RHRHW)

On the callsite you can get `const char*` as:

```
std::string s = byteArrayToString(bytes);
const char *str = s.c_str();
```

Comment: Nice, but apparently [a library requires the `char *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264516/what-is-the-proper-way-to-create-a-temporary-char-and-print-to-it#comment13198355_10264516).

Comment: This leaves out the ':' between bytes and doesn't return as char *. I realize that this might be a better way to go about it, but without refactoring my code, could you tell me how to do what I'm asking?

Comment: You can use the `c_str()` method of `string` to get the `char *`.

Comment: @Nawaz, Even if not, you can still copy it from that to something else and use it.

Comment: Or if you are ABSOLUTELY SURE that the library wont be modifying the strings in any way you can use a const_cast

Comment: @MMavipc Probably still better to go copy it and then send a stern letter to the author for not making it `const char *`.